# getting incorrect topic[0] from web3.utils.sha3

Tags: web3js, keccak

I have the following event:

`event DelegatedManagerSet(bytes32 indexed loanId, address indexed delegator, address indexed delegated, bool isActive);`

I am trying to calculate the value of topic[0].

I tried hashing the following strings:

`"DelegatedManagerSet(bytes3,address,address,bool)"`,
`"DelegatedManagerSet(bytes3 indexed,address indexed,address indexed,bool)"`,
`"DelegatedManagerSet(bytes3, address, address, bool)"`,
`"DelegatedManagerSet(bytes3 indexed, address indexed, address indexed, bool)"`,

But none of them gave out the correct hash.
The correct topic[0] is 0x0eef4f90457a741c97d76fcf13fa231fefdcc7649bdb3cb49157c37111c98433

Please help me out on this one, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple typo. Should have used bytes32 instead of bytes3. Sorry to bring this here.